# Как скопировать данные с dbf файла в Data Set с помощью C# ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb, dbf

Здравствуйте, нужно считать данные с dbf файла (созданного в Visual Fox Pro) с помощью DataAdapter в DataSet. Использую код:

```
Conn = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=D:\Work;Password=;Mode=ReadWrite;Collating Sequence=MACHINE;Extended Properties=dBASE III";
...
string strCmd2 = @"select * from D:\Work\rrk.dbf;";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strCmd2, Conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Код взят с метанита, так что вряд ли есть какие-то ошибки, но вместо таблицы с данными выдает только колонки -- заполненных строк с данными нет. Подозреваю, что проблема может быть в том, что недостаточно прав, т.к. если открыть этот файл в DbfNavigator, программа просит дать право открыть файл в "монопольном доступе". Как скопировать данные с файла в Data Set?

Comment: Или может кто-то знает где взять документацию для DotNetDBF? Использовал бы эту библиотеку, но доков никаких не нашел, а самому разобраться не получается.

Comment: А данные прочитались или нет? Вы проверяли есть тут `ds.Tables[0];` что-нибудь или нет?

Comment: @Bulson, нет, не проверял. А как посмотреть?

Comment: Про отладку слышали? Про точки останова?

Comment: @Bulson, это понятно. В этом объекте я нашел только свойство Tables.Count, которое равно 1, ведь таблица создана. Как посмотреть отдельные строки в таблице? Как называются переменные или свойства в объекте ds? Ведь там много чего.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
string Conn = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data 
Source=D:\Work;Password=;Mode=ReadWrite;Collating Sequence=MACHINE;Extended 
 Properties=dBASE III";
...
await Task.Run(() =>
{
   this.Invoke(new InvokeDelegate(
   () =>
     {
       using (OleDbConnection ourConnect= new OleDbConnection(Conn ))
       {
        string strCmd2 = @"select * from rrk";
        OleDbCommand MyQueryAdap = new OleDbCommand(strCmd2 , ourConnect);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(MyQueryAdap);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
      }
    }
   ));
});
```

Comment: Вы мастер имен: `OleDbCommand MyQueryAdap `. Команду назвать адаптером, да еще и с большой буквы, хотя это локальная переменная, чтоб никто вообще в коде не мог разобраться. Когда такое встречаешь в реальном рабочем коде хочется бить молотком по голове того, кто такое написал.

Comment: Результат точно такой же, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: ААА, так у тебя просто DataGridView не заполнен, теперь понятно

Comment: Попробуй применить await как я выше написал, обновление datagridview просто так через Refresh() не выйдет, я пробовал проверял, работает на Entity Framework

Comment: `Refresh` используется для **прорисовки** контрола. Он бесполезен и не нужен для обновления **данных**. Очень часто вижу эту ошибку: лепят `Refresh` не к месту.

Comment: Совершенно с вами согласен, что особенно раздражает